# Transparent Text Box - Image Overlay

Tags: html, css, image, text, overlay

How can you overlay text over an image with a background, like this

[image: Example]

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="images/slide1.jpg"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaBho

```
 <div>
  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, placeat!</h4>
  <img src="http://rack.0.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE0LzA4LzI0LzVkL21pbGV5ZG9nLmEzMDVjLmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/1750ef37/ade/miley-dog.jpg">
</div>
```

### css

```
div{position: relative;
  margin: 35px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h4{
  background-color: rgba(174, 0, 0, 0.51);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this [demo](http://jsbin.com/vinuko/1/edit) ?

Important things:

The parent div has to have `position: relative` and the text div `position: absolute`. Then you position it on the image with `top: ?; left: ?; bottom: ?` and `text-align: center`.

Here is the **HTML**:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://www.primolo.de/archiv/BrAlIbKe/hp_bilder/luftballons2_v-gallery_1_.jpg"/>
    <div id="slider-text">This is awesome</div>
</div>
```

And the **CSS**:

```
#slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

#slider-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 30px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(200, 50, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Most of the stuff was not necessary, but I think it looks pretty nice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but as the first answer was posted first I will have to mark that answer as correct. But don't be disappointed as your answer was just as good!